# can't find blueprint in packaged unreal project

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

i'm working on a game in unreal, and just for funsies i decided to package my project to see how it would work outside the editor. for some reason it doesn't, its says fatal error followed by a bunch of error codes.

I tried going through the log, which can be found here: [Link to download on Mega.nz](https://mega.nz/#!gkdyQQ7a!XRIKJ_h7uqI5RQGKddUJcJ8zdcYIU-dHQTFfpoHsTPs)

the log says it couldn't find the blueprint for my "BasicBullet", although the editor can (it both compiles and runs fine in the editor). That message is followed by somehting i don't understand, and then a fatal error message. can someone explain what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, all i had to do was go to the config folder, in the project and edit the DefaultEditor.ini file.
i changed bDontLoadBlueprintOutsideEditor= true to bDontLoadBlueprintOutsideEditor= false and now it works perfectly.

been struggling with this problem for days now, and the solution was so simple.